# Using a property of a model in an image tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I use a property of a model in an image tag?

I thought this would work -

```
      <%= image_tag('#{somemodel.name}.png') %>
```

But that renders -

```
<img src="/assets/#{somemodel.name}.png" alt="#{video.name}">
```

How can I get it to put the name property of somemodel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single quotes don't allow for interpolation. Try

```
<%= image_tag("#{somemodel.name}.png") %>
```

or

```
<%= image_tag(somemodel.name + ".png") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
<%= image_tag(somemodel.name + '.png') %>
```